# Limit product price to not pass beneath zero when using product options with negative values

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to use Opencart as a system to buy from clients, not sell, which I know can be done. I'm not sure as to how much coding needs to be changed or added, but I don't think it's too much that has to be done. I have done a lot of research and have tried doing my own work to get this working as I described, but have had no luck. Not even on Opencart community forums.

I'm going to try to be as elaborate as I can into describing what I have done and what my problems are because I wish to get this resolved and working as planned.

Problem #1 - Negative Integers to Zero on Products (but not removing them from options)

Since I buy from Clients, I have added product options with negative integers which reflect the base price of a product (whether it's damaged, missing components, etc.) that we will pay for. There are options where it will put the Price to a negative value, which I do not want to happen. I want the price to not pass beneath $0.00 and to also make sure this value carries over to the shopping cart. I have done a lot of research on PHP coding to do this, and I'm not sure what to edit to make this happen or even if it will work as I desire or even if it's the correct way of doing it.

Problem #2 - Instead of a traditional Shopping Cart check out with payment options, provide only an invoice that is also e-mailed to both the client and myself.

Since we do not sell products but buy them, we don't pay for anything until we receive the clients products to verify it's condition.

I will provide any code necessary from core files of Opencart.

Comment: Did you install opencart?

Comment: Yes I have. It's installed and live. I'll link you to my website showing you more in depth what I'm talking about.   http://exchangegamesforcash.com/ocart/index.php?route=product/product&path=20_68&product_id=54

Comment: When are using tag *OpenCart* You are making sure that users following/watching this tag will read Your question. Those users are well understanding what OpenCart is. There is also no need (even it is unwanted) to post here any code of the core files of OpenCart. You should only provide Your own code changes so that we can try and reproduce Your problem. Since there are no code changes yet in Your project and Your question is solely theoretical, it's hard to solve any problem. You are saying You have done a lot of research on PHP and OpenCart - but does this mean that You are a PHP developer?